# linq to sql designer in .net 3.5

Tags: linq-to-sql

where  can i find the linq to sql designer in .net 3.5 sp1?

do i need to install something to work with it

Answer (score 1):

Create a new "LINQ to SQL Classes" item under Add New Item in the Solution Explorer's context menu.

By the way, Microsoft considers LINQ to SQL obsolete now, preferring the Entity Framework going forward.

Answer (score 0):

It is Visual Studio.

[Here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Introducing-LINQ-to-SQL-Designer-using-Visual-Studio-2008/) a tutorial may help you

Answer (score 0):

[Visual LINQ Query Builder](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vlinq) is what you are looking for.

Comment: No he isn't, he needs the built-in LINQ to SQL Designer.

Comment: I think he need to elaborate his question.